# Can adding conditional diagnostics in Java be zero cost when they are off?

Tags: java, enums, diagnostics

This is really a question about Java, not c++.

The idea is you'd like to be able to add in-line diagnostics that you could turn on and off by setting a flag. And you'd like the cost to be low and near or at zero when the flag is turned off.

Years ago I implemented a class I called "Debugger" in C++ that did this. The design uses enums for the flag names so you can have code that's readable and efficient and type-safe. The usage looks like this.

```
enum DebugBits {
    testCondition1,
    testCondition2,
    testCondition3
    nTestConditions
}`
Debugger testDebug("testDebug", nTestConditions,
                    "condition1",
                    "condition2",
                    "condition3");

Critical::doStuff()
{
    ...
    if (testDebug.on(testCondition2))
        doSomethingSpecial();
    ...
}
```

This was easily implemented with bits indexed with the enum values and inline methods. It works well in a large real-time system and has very near zero cost when the debugging is turned off. Its a valuable tool.

Anyway, back to the question. Today I was looking at doing the same thing in Java, for personal reasons, but given that you can't subclass enums, and yet it would be good to use them, its not so easy to keep the declaration clear and the usage in the code brief.

So here's an implementation that works, and is somewhat efficient. The questions are,

- Can the implementation be more efficient?
- At the same time can the usage in the code be kept clear?

I suspect there are better Java coders out there that may have better ideas about how to do this. Add a package at the top and this should compile and run. There is another class at the bottom to demonstrate the usage. Note that there's lots more that should be in this, but this is the core part the is interesting. Well... to me.

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Debugger {
    private final EnumSet mEnumSet;
    private final BitSet  mBits;
    private final Vector<String> mNames;

    public Debugger(EnumSet es) {
        mEnumSet = es;
        mBits = new BitSet(es.size());
        mNames = new Vector<>();
        for (Object i : mEnumSet)
            mNames.add(i.toString());
    }

    public void set(int bit) {
        mBits.set(bit);
    }

    public void set(String bitName) {
        int bit = mNames.indexOf(bitName);
        if (bit >= 0)
            mBits.set(bit);
    }

    public boolean on(int bit) {
        return mBits.get(bit);
    }

    public boolean on(Object arg) {
        if (arg.getClass() == Enum.class) {
            int bit = ((Enum)arg).ordinal();
            return mBits.get(bit);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean on(String bitName) {
        int bit = mNames.indexOf(bitName);
        return bit >= 0 && mBits.get(bit);
    }
}

class SampleUsage {
    static class Debug extends Debugger {
        enum Bits {
            zero, one, two, three;
            public static final EnumSet<Bits> bits = EnumSet.allOf(Bits.class);
        }
        public Debug() {
            super(Bits.bits);
        }
    }
    public static final Debug debug = new Debug();

    public SampleUsage() {}

    void doStuff() {
        if (debug.on(Debug.Bits.three))
            showDebugInfo();
        if (debug.on("three"))
            showDebugInfo();
    }

    private void showDebugInfo() {}
}
```

Comment: The question may be more suitable for [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). One thing regarding type safety could be using generics for the Debugger class to restrict the type of the Enum and the parameter for the `on(Object)` method. `Debug` can then be defined as e.g. `static class Debug extends Debugger<Debug.Bits>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you’ve missed the point of `EnumSet<>`.  The `EnumSet<>` is your type-safe set of highly efficient debug flags.

```
enum Debug {
    FLAG0, FLAG1, FLAG2;
}

EnumSet<Debug> debug = EnumSet.noneOf(Debug.class);

debug.add(Debug.FLAG0);

if (debug.contains(Debug.FLAG0)) {
    showDebugInfo0();   // Will be executed.
}

if (debug.contains(Debug.FLAG1)) {
    showDebugInfo1();   // Will not be executed because FLAG1 was not added to the EnumSet.
}
```

There is no need to translate the `enum` values into ordinals, and add that ordinal to a `BitSet`.  `EnumSet<>` is already implemented using something like a `BitSet` (except the `EnumSet<>` is of a fixed size, based on the number of identifiers in the `Enum`, so cannot be extended to an arbitrary length).

If you want to test if a flag is set by name, you can use the `Enum.valueOf()` to convert the name into the correct `Enum`, and test if the `EnumSet<>` contains that.

```
if (debug.contains(Enum.valueOf(Debug.class, "FLAG2")) {
    showDebugInfo2();     // Also not executed, because FLAG2 was not added to the EnumSet.
}
```

Again, no need for a `Vector<String>` that contains all of the `Enum` names, which you must find the `.indexOf()`.  The `Enum` comes with that method built-in.  `Vector<>` was not an efficient choice to use anyway, since `Vector<>` operations are automatically `synchronized`, so are slightly slower than an equivalent `ArrayList<>`.

**Note**: Minor difference: `.indexOf()` returns -1 when not found; `Enum.valueOf()` will raise an `IllegalArgumentException` if you give it an unknown identifier name.

---

Assuming you want `.on()`, not `.contains()`, and you want simpler test flag by name usage in your code, we’ll need to wrap the `EnumSet<>` in another class.  This `Debug` class might look like:

```
class Debug<T extends Enum<T>> {
    private final Class<T> enum_class;
    private final EnumSet<T> flags;

    public Debug(Class<T> enum_class) {
        this.enum_class = enum_class;
        flags = EnumSet.noneOf(enum_class);
    }

    public void set(T flag) {
        flags.add(flag);
    }

    public boolean on(T flag) {
        returns flags.contains(flag);
    }

    public void set(String flag_name) {
        flags.add(Enum.valueOf(enum_class, flag_name));
    }

    public boolean on(String flag_name) {
        return flags.contains(Enum.valueOf(enum_class, flag_name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I think you are right: I missed the point of EnumSet<> and was too driven by trying to copy the c++ implementation.

Comment: Rereading your comment about  Vector.indexOf() vs Enum.valueOf(), this class is certainly not something you would want to generate an exception. The indexOf() was certainly the thing that led me to add strings and to use ordinalOf(). In the end, try/catch is a small price to pay to stay in the language rather than departing from enums to ints.

Comment: Actually, I believe it is something that you’d really want to generate an exception.  `debug.set("TRACE_RECIEVER")` should be an exception because a spelling error of a flag name shouldn’t be silently ignored.  I wouldn’t provide the `.on(String flag_name)` variant, because the code that uses the debug class should be written using the actual enum’s for the maximum possible speed; string to enum lookup is a performance penalty you don’t want in a “low or near zero” cost diagnostic framework.  It is “ok” during setup, and immediate feedback that you spelt an identifier wrong is important.

Comment: My intended design is a bit different. As you know using enums would be the proper way for most every task, and it would be efficient, as desired. Also, because the enums are typesafe that would prevent (or identify) programming errors. String usage on the other hand, is the exceptional usage. Generally this would be used by a distant system unrelated to the class declaring the enums such as an RPC interface or a command line tool that can change debug bits to turn diagnostics on and off. I see no value in that usage generating an exception. At most, it ought indicate the misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

So with minor mods to your implementation, it shows brevity and clarity and uses fewer resources. The Enum.valueOf() I missed entirely. The string conversion is a goal I did not describe, but is useful when trying to set bits through a subsystem that is unaware of the class containing the enums, but the user knows the names. I got parts of it right, but you got me out of the weeds. Thanks much.

Oh... and I changed the name.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

class Diagnostic<T extends Enum<T>> {
    private final Class<T> enum_class;
    private final EnumSet<T> flags;

    public Diagnostic(Class<T> enum_class) {
        this.enum_class = enum_class;
        this.flags = EnumSet.noneOf(enum_class);
    }

    public void set(T flag) {
        flags.add(flag);
    }

    public boolean on(T flag) {
        return flags.contains(flag);
    }

    public void set(String flag_name) {
        try {
            flags.add(Enum.valueOf(enumClass, flag_name));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public boolean on(String flag_name) {
        try {
            return flags.contains(Enum.valueOf(enumClass, flag_name));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class SampleUsage {
    enum DiagBits {
        zero, one, two, three;
    }
    public static final Diagnostic<DiagBits> diag = new Diagnostic<>(DiagBits.class);

    public SampleUsage() {}

    void doStuff() {    
        if (diag.on(DiagBits.three))
            showDebugInfo();
        if (diag.on("three"))
            showDebugInfo();
    }

    private void showDebugInfo() {}
}
```

Comment: You don’t need `Debug extends Diagnostic`.  Move `Bits` directly inside `SampleUsage` and use `public static final Diagnostic<Bits> debug = new Diagnostic<>(Bits.class);`.  And the `bits` member is unnecessary as well.

Comment: Ha, ha. I moved Bits outside roughly 5 minutes before your comment. But I did not realize the Debug class was superfluous. Good call. Fixed.